Can kotlin annotation processor be add properties using Kotlin annotation processor?
Lombok in Java can. But I wonder if it's possible in Kotlin.
Looking at the documentation for KAPT, and how to use the KAPT implementation plugin, it doesn't seem possible. Is my understanding correct? https://kotlinlang.org/docs/kapt.html#keep-java-compiler-s-annotation-processors https://github.com/square/kotlinpoet
I tried implementing a custom kapt to add the property, but it seemed impossible.
